# In React Router v6, can I use createBrowserRouter to put a conditional route inside the universal root route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With my current router, the `Root` component renders fine at `"/"` but the `Blog` component does not show up:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/*' element={<Root />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Blog />} />
      <Route path='code' element={<Code />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

I have tried removing the `"*"`, but that seems to do nothing. Is there a way to get a conditional route nested within a 'universal' route using `createBrowserRouter`?